# I have an error when i initialize gradle on my CI

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gitlab

I made an CI with Gitlab for a Flutter application and I have an error when i initialize gradle.

The error:

```
$ flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in codingroomevents...               8.5s
$ flutter build apk --release
Initializing gradle...                                          
ProcessException: Process         "/builds/user/codingroomevents/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip


Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable     (connect failed)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you cannot download missing gradle distribution because network is unreachable. Are you running the CI in a docker image? Can you login with this docker image and run a network command like `curl www.google.it` to see if you are connected on internet?

Comment: My flutter packages get works so I am connected on internet and that work. I run my CI in this docker image : https://hub.docker.com/r/nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker

Comment: if you run `wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` does it work? Are you under some kind of proxy?

Comment: I have a proxy but i think my docker image don't need it because i can resolve my dependencies with flutter packages get without proxy. The command return this : $ wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip 
         **NEXT LINE**           /bin/bash: line 80: wget: command not found. I will install wget

Comment: So you don't have wget command in the docker image. Okay. But the error is explicit. Java cannot reach the URL to download your gradle distribution. You need to focus on that.

Comment: Ok i will try to setup the proxy before initializing gradle, thanks. It is possible that a slow connection is affecting the build ?

Comment: Yep sometimes a slow connection makes `java socket` to raise a `timeout exception` so it fails and you need to relaunch it.

Comment: Having the same problem. Network is available in every other manner other than in the terminal AFTER running `./gradlew signingReport`